# C++ pass in vector to function template

Tags: c++, vector

I want to check whether two vectors have any elements in common. What's wrong with this syntax?

```
// Check whether the current list and the input l2 share any nodes or not 
bool shared(const VectorList< NODETYPE > &l2); 

template< typename NODETYPE > //SHARED
bool VectorList< NODETYPE>::shared(const VectorList< NODETYPE > &l2)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)vList.size(); i++)
      {
        for (int j = i; j < (int)l2.size() ; j++)
            {
                    if (vList[i] == l2[j])
                    {
                        return(1);
                    }
            }
      }

    return(0);

}
```

Comment: You might want to post why you think something is wrong with your code. If it's a compiler error, the name of the compiler and its version might help, too.

Comment: Always post compiler error also. They were done to check the syntax, so that people hadn't do it by themselves.

Comment: You know `std::vector` is no slouch you should use it as well as the STL algorithms designed for the standard template containers.

Comment: What error comes up? Always post the error message when dealing with syntax problems.

Comment: Ok, after you haven't bothered for 8hrs to even tell us what problem you are seeing, I'm voting to close this as not a real question. Feel free to provide the information necessary to properly answer. (If by then the question is already closed, flag a mod to reopen it, after you have provided the information.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have implemented VectorList as (similar to) a standard container, I'd consider writing (see [`find_first_of`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find_first_of.html)):

```
template<typename T>
bool VectorList<T>::shared(const VectorList<T> &l2) const // <-- NOTE added const
{
    return end() != std::find_first_of(
        begin(), end(), 
        l2.begin(), l2.end());
}
```

Note that the (worst-case) runtime complexity will still be quadratic (or `O(n*m)`)

Answer (score 2):

Is your vector ordered? Because if not, you should not do j = i, or it won't find some shared values, i.e

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

If you start your second *for loop* with j = i, you'll never find the shared value "2". So you need to start your second *for loop* from the beginning of the vector each time (j = 0)